# bsTooltip with id='xx.yy.zz'

Tags: r, twitter-bootstrap, shiny

**Shiny ui.r snippet**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

# this works (in browser - there is tooltip) 
bsTooltip(id = "someInput", title = "This is an input", 
        placement = "left", trigger = "hover")
```

versus

```
# this (silently) does not work (in browser - there is no tooltip) 
  bsTooltip(id = "some.input", title = "This is an input", 
        placement = "left", trigger = "hover")
# prints
<script>$(document).ready(function() {setTimeout(function() 
{addTooltip('some.input', 'This is an input', 'left', 'hover')}, 100)});
</script>
```

How to handle cases where there are shiny input IDs having dots? Or, if shiny input is "xx.yy.zz" what corresponding name (for js script side) should be used?

**ui.r - to reproduce**

```
bootstrapPage(
textInput("xx.yy.zz", "Text Input", "xx.yy.zz here tooltip fails"), 
textInput("xx_yy_zz", "Text Input", "text xx_yy_zz"), 
bsTooltip("xx.yy.zz", "Text Input Tooltip - fails",placement='bottom'),
bsTooltip("xx_yy_zz", "Text Input Tooltip - ok",placement='bottom')
)
```

**server.r**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {})
```

The right tag should rather be shinyBS. Currently I do not have 2k to make it.